# Set library path when configuring/building OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

I am trying to cross-compile OpenSSL for Android, using [Dockcross](https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross/blob/master/android-arm64/Dockerfile). It seems like Dockcross is configured for CMake, so I need to set some variables myself (I'd like to see then if I can update dockcross for this use-case).

I managed to run `./Configure` as follows:

```
ANDROID_NDK=/usr/aarch64-linux-android PATH=${PATH}:/usr/aarch64-linux-android/bin CC=clang \
CPPINCLUDES=/usr/aarch64-linux-android/sysroot/usr/include ./Configure android-arm64 no-shared
```

Then I run `make`:

```
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/aarch64-linux-android/bin make
```

And I get the following error:

> /usr/aarch64-linux-android/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin_so.o: No such file or directory

Among others, I had to set `CPPINCLUDES`, which I found [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/Configure#L635), and there I see it appear in the build output (`-I/usr/aarch64-linux-android/sysroot/usr/include`). Also, the missing `crtbegin_so.o` is in `/usr/aarch64-linux-android/sysroot/usr/lib`, but I can't find a way to specify that path.

I tried `LDFLAGS`, `LDLIBS`, `LIBRARY_PATH` in the `./Configure` script, but nothing seems to work.

How should I set that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually, I should have been setting the `sysroot` from the beginning on. I missed it because it is documented for the older `./configure` script, but I did not see it documented in the newer `./Configure`, though it works:

```
ANDROID_NDK=/usr/aarch64-linux-android PATH=${PATH}:/usr/aarch64-linux-android/bin CC=clang ./Configure --sysroot /usr/aarch64-linux-android/sysroot android-arm64 --prefix=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} no-shared
```

I believe that `ANDROID_NDK` could be set by dockcross directly, and maybe the PATH, too. Not sure if there is a way around `CC=clang` here.